# Append to Kotlin data class ArrayList

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have the following `data class` intended for use in an Android application running Kotlin version 1.2.51:

`data class Data(var a: ArrayList<String>, var b: String)`

As you can see, `a` is an `ArrayList`. I want to append elements from another array into `a`. I've tried this:

```
itemsToAppend.forEach {
    Data.a.add(it)
}
```

However, Android Studio determines that `a` is an unresolved reference. How exactly does one append an item to such an `ArrayList`?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you address `a` as a static field in the way `Data.a` ? Your `a` is a member field, and should be addressed as a `Data().a` or `val data = Data(); data.a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data classes are not object classes. You will have to initialise them before you can use it

```
val d= Data(ArrayList(), "demo")
itemsToAppend.forEach {
    d.a.add(it)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create an instance of Data:

```
var a: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
var data = Data(a, "something")
```

and use `data` in your loop

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access you list *staticly*  do this:

```
data class D(var a: ArrayList<String>) { // a can't be used as D.a
   companion object {
      var ab: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList() // ab can be used as D.ab
   }
}
```